# Positive solution of a linear system with integer coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, integers

Suppose that $b_1,\dots,b_m \in \mathbb Z^n$ are not linearly independent over $\mathbb Z$ (otherwise the problem is trivial).  Given another element $w\in \mathbb Z^n$  is there a way to determine (algorithmically) if $w$ can be written as a linear combination of $b_1,\dots,b_m$ with **positive** integer coefficients?

Edit:  the $b_i$ under my consideration have exactly one negative component, and all the other components are either 1 or 0, and the sum of the components is 0.  I say this, because in this special case there may be a specific solution.

Comment: In the case that some components of the $b_i$s are positive and some negative, there might be a way to relax the constraint that the coefficients must be positive

Comment: Yes, the $b_i$ are not required to have positive components.

Comment: Yes, I understood.  I was just saying that it is not the case.

Comment: It's decidable because it's a special case of ILP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming

Comment: Ok, I got you now.  Actually the $b_i$ under my consideration have at least one negative component, and the sum of the components is zero.  I should update the question.